# Packer cannot communicate with AWS windows server 2016 instances to build custom ami

Tags: amazon-ec2, packer, windows-server-2016

I am using packer 0.12.1 to build an AWS ami based on the existing windows server 2016 ami.

The way I used to get it to work with windows server 2012 is to specify in the packer template:

```
"communicator": "winrm",
"winrm_username": "Administrator",
"winrm_use_ssl": true,
"winrm_insecure": true,
"user_data_file":"./ec2-userdata-winserver2016.ps1",
```

And the user data file would look like:

```
<powershell>

write-output "Running User Data Script"
write-host "(host) Running User Data Script"

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine -Force -ErrorAction Ignore

# Don't set this before Set-ExecutionPolicy as it throws an error
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

# Remove HTTP listener
Remove-Item -Path WSMan:\Localhost\listener\listener* -Recurse

$Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertstoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "packer"
New-Item -Path WSMan:\LocalHost\Listener -Transport HTTPS -Address * -CertificateThumbPrint $Cert.Thumbprint -Force

# WinRM
write-output "Setting up WinRM"
write-host "(host) setting up WinRM"

cmd.exe /c winrm quickconfig -q
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config" '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/winrs" '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="1024"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/service" '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/client" '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/service/auth" '@{Basic="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/client/auth" '@{Basic="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/service/auth" '@{CredSSP="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS" "@{Port=`"5986`";Hostname=`"packer`";CertificateThumbprint=`"$($Cert.Thumbprint)`"}"
cmd.exe /c netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote administration" new enable=yes
cmd.exe /c netsh firewall add portopening TCP 5986 "Port 5986"
cmd.exe /c net stop winrm
cmd.exe /c sc config winrm start= auto
cmd.exe /c net start winrm

</powershell>
```

This works fine in windows server 2012, but not anymore in windows server 2016.

For server 2016, the output of packer is:

```
==> eu-west-1-builder: Waiting for auto-generated password for instance...
    eu-west-1-builder: It is normal for this process to take up to 15 minutes,
    eu-west-1-builder: but it usually takes around 5. Please wait.
    eu-west-1-builder:  
    eu-west-1-builder: Password retrieved!
==> eu-west-1-builder: Waiting for WinRM to become available...
```

And it hangs until timeout.

As AWS release windows server 2016 ami fairly recently, I couldn't find much information. I am not really a windows guru (I am usually on linux)

Any help / suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually the issue I am experiencing is on windows server 2016 nano.

Comment: From the release announcement "SSM Agent – An upgraded version of our SSM Agent is now used in place of EC2Config." That is probably a hint of what to look into. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/run-windows-server-2016-on-amazon-ec2/

Comment: FWIW, I replicated your experience using Packer 0.12.3 where your userdata works just fine on Win2K16 Full, but does not work (for me) on nano.  I tried both winrms and winrm methods (ie encrypted and plaintext) and both of them just hung waiting for winrm to come up.  Typically that means something in the userdata did not execute properly.  Your best bet is to start up a plain nano session, connect manually, and run the commands one at a time until you find what barfs.

Comment: Did you get it to work? I am in the situation. Have tried this https://github.com/magudb/packer-sitecore/blob/master/AWS/template.json

Comment: Didn't get it to work no. I ended up not using nano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing "winrm_username" to something other than Administrator

As per Packer [documentation](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/azure.html)The default user name is packer not root as in other builders. Most distros on Azure do not allow root to SSH to a VM hence the need for a non-root default user. Set the ssh_username option to override the default value.